# Favicon background color is not transparent for Stack Overflow Business page

Tags: bug, design, favicon

The Stack Overflow [Business page's](https://business.stackoverflow.com/?ref=topbar_help) favicon's background color is not transparent, so when we navigate to some other tab the business page's favicon is looking different.

The same issue is not happens for the Stack Overflow site's favicon.

Zoom: 100%
OS: Windows 8.1 pro
Firefox: 46.0
Chrome: 50.0.2661.94 m

Screenshot attached for the reference:

1. When the business page is in active, the fav-icon is looking good.
2. When navigate to some other tab, the fav-icon having the display issue.

[image: Fav icon background color issue]

**Update:**

After inspect the page, I see below are the icons used for the pages, those are different in size and background.

For Business page: http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/450622/favicon-144x144.png?t=1462297742399

For Stack Overflow page: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d

Comment: hmmm 3 years later, its still there.