# The Stack Overflow Blog's favicon doesn't have a transparent background

Tags: bug, blog, favicon

The [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/)'s favicon should be replaced by an asset with a transparent background.

[image]

Comment: @user5226582 I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm just requesting that it be standardised to [the normal SO favicon](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico).

Comment: Oh, I see. Nevermind!

Comment: Personally, I kinda like it isn't transparent, so I know which of my tabs are blog ones.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322209/favicon-background-color-is-not-transparent-for-stack-overflow-business-page?rq=1

Comment: I literally can't see any problem without a red freehand circle.

Comment: Ironically, it would need to be a *transparent* red freehand circle, or you wouldn't be able to see the problem, either.